# Deprecate old-school AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I got an issue "Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerAjaxHandler()" when I am trying to upgrade typo 3 8 to typo 3 9.5.13.

My code is:

if (TYPO3_MODE == 'BE') {

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerAjaxHandler(
    'BackendController::functionloaderAction',
    'DmprextVendor\DmprExt\Controller\BackendController->functionloaderAction'
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your need to check out this change log: registerAjaxHandler ist deprecated on TYPO3 v8 & v9.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/7.6/Breaking-69916-RegisteredAJAXHandlersReplacedByRoutes.html

Comment: Please Mark my answer as useful :)